# How can pass html special characters in smtp headers Array like QR code

Tags: email, smtp, special-characters

**This is my code i am sending Qrimage and also use br tag in message body ..but in email it showing me br tag and Qrimage not printing**

```
$headers = array ('From' => $email_from, 'To' => $to, 'Subject' => $email_subject, 'Reply-To' => $email_address);
$smtp = Mail::factory('smtp', array ('host' => $host, 'port' => $port, 'auth' => true, 'username' => $username, 'password' => $password));
$mail = $smtp->send($to, $headers, $email_body);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass it like this .It may Help you

```
$headers = array ('From' => $email_from, 'To' => $to, 'Subject' => $email_subject, 'Reply-To' => $email_address,'MIME-Version' => "1.0",'Content-type' => "text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n\r\n");
```